# Dynamic query as Inbound connections to MULE

Tags: esb, mule

I am trying to create an SQL query inbound connection to my Mule server but I want the query itself to be dynamic (meaning I want to add a value such as: `SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE TimeStamp > SomeDynamicVariable`).

How would I go about creating such an inbound connection, considering that I want to poll the database every so often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mule, what you want to achieve is called "requesting" (ie. consuming an endpoint with a custom expression) and is not handled with inbound endpoints.

To achieve your goal you need:

- A global JDBC endpoint using a Mule expression for the timestamp value, for example like this:

  ```
  <jdbc:query key="myQuery" value="SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE TimeStamp > #[payload]"/>
  ```
- A [Quartz inbound endpoint to generate an event](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Quartz+Transport+Reference#QuartzTransportReference-EventGeneratorJob) containing in the payload the timestamp to be used in query,
- A [message enricher](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Message+Enricher) to request from the endpoint and set the resulting value in the current payload (target = #[payload]).

D.

Comment: Thank you for response. I"m going over your links and something is still missing in my understanding. I would like to change the timestamp (ussed in the select query) at every event, How would i incorperate a dynamic timestamp in to the quertz event generator?

Comment: I'll try to exaplin myself a little better, is it possible to use the enricher in order to atler the generator's payload?   Is there some sort of example (even somewhat diffrent) i can look at for this? because i"m having some problem understanding (and writing) this flow.

Comment: I see what you mean: it seems you'll need a transformer after the Quartz inbound endpoint in order to set the payload to the timestamp you want.

Comment: Regarding the timestamp value, is it always the current system timestamp or a value you strictly control? If the latter, my above proposal applies, but if the former you can probably get away with a way simpler solution by using an expression directly in a standard inbound JDBC endpoint, like: #[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss]